# Promise <pending> error seen and my input data not writing to Mongo DB. I dont know what is promise here

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Actually im trying to log user input data into Mongo Db through create account page. But the user data is not writing to my mongo db. I console the saves user and its logged in console but not in my MONGO DB. Im new to this please help what is promise and how to resolve this issue.

**Post route**

````
  //Creating New User in Mongo DB with user input values.
    const user = new User({
        // name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });


    try{
       const savedUser = user.save();

        console.log(savedUser);

       res.send(savedUser);
       //console.log(res.send({user: user._id}));

   }catch(err){

      console.log(err);
       //res.sendStatus(400).send(err);
   }
})```



Mongodb connection

dotenv.config();

//Connect to Mongo DB using mongoose
mongoose.connect( process.env.DATABASE_CONNECT, {useNewUrlParser: true},
    () => console.log('Connected to Mongo DB')
);


[Error Image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rgp3.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, I think your request is still pending. Return the status code of 'Created Successfully'

```
try {
    user.save();
    console.log(savedUser);
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Saved successfully!'
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Now able to see the user entered data in console but not in my Mongo Db collections. I feel some thing is wromg im connection. Can you help me out. How to write the data in Mongo DB. 

Console Output:

{ date: 2019-09-25T06:05:01.687Z,
  _id: 5d8b0457e0d1c31ccc1e37bf,
  email: 'Tharun@gmail.com',
  password: 'Tharun@1234' }

Answer (score 0):

This is how I connect my app to mongoDB cluster using mongoose. Hope it helps

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // To use body parser to get data
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // For mongoose connection
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-65bot.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority') // If you are using a cluster, this will be generated for you
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connected Successfully to MongoDB Atlas!');
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas!');
    console.error(error);
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
}); // This sets header to avoid CORS
```

Comment: Thank you so much @odinaka. After your first comment i solved my issue and able to return data in console. But in my .env file my db password is not correct. So data is not writing to mongoDB. its working fine. Thanks alot again.